# DataTables warning: table id=tblData i don't compile my program

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

This is my file.js

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {

    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/admin/category/GetAll",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name", "width": "50%" },
            { "data": "displayOrder", "width": "20%" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/Admin/category/Upsert/${data}" class='btn btn-success text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:100px;'>
                                    <i class='far fa-edit'></i> Edit
                                </a>
                                &nbsp;
                                <a onclick=Delete("/Admin/category/Delete/${data}") class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:100px;'>
                                    <i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i> Delete
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            `;
                }, "width": "30%"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "No records found."
        },
        "width": "100%"
    });
}
```

When I try to compile I get a message

[image]

I checked the controller code and I did not see anything as an add-on I also attach the Index.cshtml file:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br />
<div class="border backgroundWhite">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Category List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a asp-action="Upsert" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Create New Category</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Display Order</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/category.js"></script>
}
```

And this is my file Controler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Uplift.DataAccess.Data.Repository.IRepository;
using Uplift.Models;
using Uplift.Utility;

namespace Uplift.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public CategoryController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public IActionResult Upsert(int? id)
        {
            Category category = new Category();
            if (id == null)
            {
                return View(category);
            }
            category = _unitOfWork.Category.Get(id.GetValueOrDefault());
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(category);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (category.Id == 0)
                {
                    _unitOfWork.Category.Add(category);
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfWork.Category.Update(category);
                }
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(category);
        }


        #region API CALLS

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll() });
            //return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.SP_Call.ReturnList<Category>(SD.usp_GetAllCategory,null)  });
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var objFromDb = _unitOfWork.Category.Get(id);
            if (objFromDb == null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while deleting." });
            }

            _unitOfWork.Category.Remove(objFromDb);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete successful." });

        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

I can not find a solution to this problem when trying to add a new category in the application on the chrome there is a problem with 'tblData' if any of you have a hint on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you visit the site mentioned in the message? Looks like there is a lot of information there.

Comment: You have "[Area("Admin")]" which should be the root of the response. I don't see "Admin" in the response.

Answer (score 0):

As you using `[Area("Admin")]` in your controller,you need to add area route to startup like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MyArea",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

   ...
});
```

You can also refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to learn more about Areas.

Answer (score 0):

This is my startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Uplift.DataAccess.Data;
using Uplift.DataAccess.Data.Repository;
using Uplift.DataAccess.Data.Repository.IRepository;
using Uplift.Utility;

namespace Uplift
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

              
            });
        }
    }
}
```